# Word count in Hibernate Query Language (hql)

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, hql

Currently I am using Hibernate Query Language (HQL). By using hql I want to create a function for getting the number of word in a function. I am not getting any clue from internet. So, guys please help me. Thank you in advance.

I want to create query like

```
SELECT post FROM Post post WHERE WORDCOUNT(post.details) > 99
```

Comment: please check, i have edited my question

Comment: I'm not sure that pure HQL would allow for the query you would need here.  One option, though perhaps not optimal, would be to just read each row into Java and count the number of words in `details` there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of a way to do this using HQL alone.  As a workaround, you can read each row into Java, and then manually count the number of words in `details`.

If you are open to using a native query, then we can try counting words by counting the number of spaces in the `details` column.  For example, on MySQL and Oracle, you could try the following query:

```
SELECT post
FROM post
WHERE LENGTH(details) - LENGTH(REPLACE(details, ' ', '')) > 98;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's working. My current query "SELECT post FROM Post post WHERE LENGTH(post.details) - LENGTH(REPLACE(post.details, ' ', ''))>98" in hql