# Hibernate, HQL: Count appearances of a specific character in a string

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I have a table named "POSTS" with "WBS" field of type varchar(50).
The values in the WBS field match the following pattern:
<number.number.number..> ex:  "1.2.3", "123.123", "123", "123.3.2.1" etc.

I need to select all records where the value of "WBS" field has two dots, one dot, or none.

My question is: How to count the appearances of a specific character in a string ?

For example, on MySQL and Oracle, I could try the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM posts
WHERE LENGTH(WBS) - LENGTH(REPLACE(WBS, '.', '')) = 1;
```

found here: [Word count in Hibernate Query Language (hql)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56642419/word-count-in-hibernate-query-language-hql)

Answer (score 2):

You can use almost the same query in HQL. Assuming your entity is called `Post` and the attribute for `WBS` is `wbs`, you can use:

```sql
SELECT p
FROM Post p
WHERE LENGTH(p.wbs) - LENGTH(REPLACE(p.wbs, '.', '')) = 1;
```